# Facebook authentication fails

Tags: php, facebook

I'm about to give up. for about a week i'm trying the simplest thing, authentication via facebook. every time I authenticatiom (via facebook login url) , getUser() and api('me'
) returns me null.

why?

the code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '306597542762982',
  'secret' => '88XXXXXX7f1',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {

  $loginUrl =  $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'user_actions.news,publish_stream,user_about_me,email,publish_actions'));

  print $loginUrl; exit;

} 

var_dump($facebook->api('me'));
```

SOS.

EDIT: POST :

```
$params = array (
  'article' => 'http://fb.raal.co.il/content/view/$id/$title',
  'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
);



$out = $facebook->api( '/me/news.reads','post', $params);

var_dump($out); exit;
```

Comment: what error /message are you getting ?

Comment: for getUser() -> int(0) , for api('me') -> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home1/raalcoil/public_html/fb/lib/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1106.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing what NullPointer quoted earlier, from user ifaour:

> Just check for the current Facebook user id $user and if it returned null then you need to reauthorize the user (or use the custom $_SESSION user id value - not recommended)

```
require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$photo_details = array('message' => 'my place');
$file='photos/my.jpg'; //Example image file
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

if ($user) {
  try {
    // We have a valid FB session, so we can use 'me'
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
// redirect to Facebook login to get a fresh user access_token
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}
```

> I've written a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-photo-to-a-users-profile-using-facebook-graph-api/66/) on how to upload a picture to the user's wall.

With the additional information, does this help? There is additional information I've found related to this, stating to attempt

`$facebook->getAccessToken();`

Apparently, that call can give either an app access token or a user access token. Depending on what you are trying to do with the access token, you will need the appropriate kind.

Alternatively, you may need to request certain permissions for what you are trying to do, which you can find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Comment: Ok, works - but now the post action wont work, i get Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Could not retrieve data from URL. thrown in /home1/raalcoil/public_html/fb/lib/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1106